# How to make LocalizedStingKey type conform to Codable protocol in Swift?

Tags: swift, codable, localizedstringkey

How to make LocalizedStingKey type conform to Codable protocol in Swift?
A simple Person struct. If do not remove country property, compiler not work.

```
struct Person: Codable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let description: LocalizedKeyString // more words in description property
}
```

Comment: Why not just change to a string instead? You can always convert a `String` to a `LocalizedStringKey` whenever you need.

Comment: Thank you Sweeper. You reminded me, and I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Edwardai did u figure out how to use them? im running into some issues too.

Comment: A quick way would be to have `let description: String`, and decode that from the JSON or Plist, etc. And use a computed var to get the localization: `var localizedDescription: String { LocalizedKeyString(description) }`.

Comment: @geethsg7 Hi, I have decided to use String type. Larme  also provided a good solution. Thanks Larme :)

Answer (score 2):

I decided to use String type and not add computed property because properties in my custom type is a little more.

If use computed property, the following code work:

```
struct Person: Codable {
let name: String
let age: Int
let description: String

var localizedDescription: LocalizedStringKey {
    return LocalizedStringKey(description)
}
```

}